# Is flutter SDK platform dependent

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, flutter

I have downloaded flutter sdk for windows. But now I've dual boot with ubuntu. Can I use the same sdk? Just copy the previous one from windows and paste it in my ubuntu or do I have to download flutter sdk again for linux?

Comment: I want to say yes... The Android SDK can be shared, but Android Studio and the flutter CLI cannot

Answer (score 0):

Flutter SDK is platform specific, here is the [Windows version entrance](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/windows)
, and here is the [macOS version entrance](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/macos).